# Оформление "прямой речи", переданной жестами

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь

> А он ещё издалека мне руками машет, глаза выпучил: Беда! Беда!
>   Оператор!!!

То ли

*А он ещё издалека мне руками машет, глаза выпучил: беда! беда!
оператор!!!*

То ли

А он ещё издалека мне руками машет, глаза выпучил: "Беда! Беда!
Оператор!!!"

И ужасно не хочется лепить точку после кавычек, - как быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) А он ещё издалека мне руками машет, глаза выпучил: "Беда! Беда! Оператор!!!"

2) А он ещё издалека мне руками машет, глаза выпучил:  беда! беда! оператор!!!

Примеры из Нацкорпуса:

1) **Стандартный вариант с прямой речью**: Он руками машет: «Отстань! Заводское летит! [Борис Екимов. На хуторе // «Новый Мир», 2002]

Смотритель выбежал на крыльцо, кричит, руками машет: «Вернуть, вернуть их, таких-сяких». [Н. С. Лесков. Темняк (1880-1890)]

Так ведь живучий какой: наземь упал,  дух из него вон, а туда же, руками машет: «Виват свобода!» [Б. В. Савинков (В. Ропшин). То, чего не было (1918)]

2) **Вводное предложение и несобственно-прямая речь**

Начинаю рассказывать, а он руками машет, я, **говорит**, это лучше вас знаю! [Р. Б. Гуль. Азеф (1958)]

Баба  на меня руками машет, чего, **мол**, ты дурак с дядей Агафоном связываешься. [С. А. Семенов. Предварительная могила (1924)

Сегодня увязалась со мной в мясную, руками машет, **кричит**, мне перед прохожими стыдно. [Н. А. Тэффи. За стеной (1910)]

**Примечание**: НПР на семантическом уровне  объединена с авторской, при этом автор говорит или думает за персонажа. НПР на синтаксическом уровне не выделяется из авторской.

Comment: То есть оба *мною нарисованных* варьянта имеют право на жизнь? О_о А кто такой этот Нацкорпус, штоб мне его слушаться, я правда не знаю, никогда в ём не бывала...

Comment: Галина, вы должны там побывать непременно. Нацкорпус в части практики - это все равно что Розенталь с Лопатиным в части теории. Прежде чем ответить на практически любой вопрос, я захожу в Нацкорпус и смотрю: а  люди-то как  пишут, в том числе уважаемые классики. http://www.ruscorpora.ru/search-main.html

Comment: Ой-ё! Заглянула... я ж там не разберусь! Плакайу. Т_Т   А *оба мною нарисованных варьянта имеют право на жизнь?*

Comment: Набираем в строе " руками машет" и нажимаем кнопку "искать". Вам предлагают 173 примера, вы их скоренько просматриваете, ищете похожие.  Верен третий вариант, а первый вариант должен быть в кавычках - обычное оформление прямой речи. Второго варианта я не нашла, но принцип такой: вы используете форму БСП, но при этом во вторую часть  помещаете  дословное высказывание персонажа (по принципу несобственно-прямой речи). Или что-то в этом роде.  Но это я еще не все ответы просмотрела, может быть, есть совсем похожие.

Comment: Он руками машет: «Отстань! Заводское летит!   В этом предложении, по-моему, закрывающие кавычки пропущены.

Comment: Проще застрелиться. 8-(

Answer (score 2):

Стандартный вариант:
*Федя вытаращил глаза и замахал на жену руками, **как бы говоря:** "Что ты, что ты..."*

Вас, я понимаю, этот вариант не устраивает...
Вообще-то получается, что **прямой речи** - как таковой - в Вашем предложении **нет**, потому что **никто никаких слов не произносит** (и даже не "продумывает").
 Читатель САМ представляет себе то, что пытаются до него "донести" жестами. Тогда почему бы нам не использовать тире?

***А он ещё издалека мне руками машет, глаза выпучил - беда! беда! оператор!!!***

Таким образом (при помощи тире) происходит разделение того, что **мы видим,** и того, что нам **хотят сказать.**

Answer (score 1):

Третий вариант - просто прямая речь, нет ни намека на то, что были только жесты. Я бы поставил слово "мол", например так:

**А он ещё издалека мне руками машет, глаза выпучил, мол, "беда! беда! оператор!!!"**

Очень хорош вариант с тире, предложенный @РиммаМихайлова:

**А он ещё издалека мне руками машет, глаза выпучил - беда! беда! оператор!!!**