# Некто пучит глаза, и его мимика передана словами, - как быть?

Tags: прямая-речь, несобственно-прямая-речь

> А он ещё издалека мне руками машет, **глаза выпучил: Беда! Беда!
>   Оператор!!!** Подошёл поближе, оглянулся по сторонам, замялся на
>   секунду: «Ну это… да я даже не знаю как! Короче… дундук!»

А можно я нарисую:

*"...глаза выпучил: беда! беда! оператор!!!"*?

Ну не смотрятся мне прописные...

Comment: По-моему, просто нельзя ставить прописные.

Comment: Три со строчной? Уверены - оформляйте ответом. Хорошо бы какой-нито примерчик, на худой конец - правило.

Comment: Вот нашел (http://www.rusyaz.ru/pr/pvs.html) Примечание 2. В восклицательных предложениях знак восклицательный может ставиться после каждого однородного члена для обозначения эмоциональной прерывистости речи, например:

Пил мёртвую! не спал ночей по девяти!
Всё отвергал: законы! совесть! веру! (Грибоедов).

Comment: Ответом оформите, пожалуста! ЛО - Ваш!

Comment: Такой вопрос уже был: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/431895/Оформление-прямой-речи-переданной-жестами.  Наверно, надо их объединить.

Comment: Римма, Вы правы, я забыла, что задавала его, но ответы - разные, и ЛОшки уже вручены... Это вина автора - не поправил с первого заходу!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно, конечно, оформить как прямую речь. Но если нет, то я бы писал со строчной:

**А он ещё издалека мне руками машет, глаза выпучил: беда! беда! оператор!!!**

Для обоснования сошлюсь на ответ Грамоты (в данном случае есть общая часть для всех восклицаний).

[**Вопрос № 238704**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=238704)

Вторую неделю задаю этот вопрос. Пожалуйста, ответьте!
Допускают ли современные правила русского языка употреблять вопросительные и восклицательные знаки в середине предложения и продолжать после них текст со строчной буквы?

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

Знаки препинания, обычные для конца предложения (вопросительный и восклицательный знак), могут ставиться после отдельных членов предложения при смысловом их подчеркивании. При этом после вопросительного или восклицательного знака используется прописная (большая) буква, как в начале самостоятельного предложения: Аннушка, наша Аннушка! С Садовой! Это ее работа! Прописные буквы заменяются строчными, если перед однородными членами предложения, требующими выделения вопросительным или восклицательным знаком, имеется обобщающее слово: *Все отвергал: законы! совесть! веру!*

Кроме этого, вопросительный и восклицательный знаки могут ставиться внутри предложения, если они относятся к вставным конструкциям или сами по себе замещают вставки, передавая отношение пишущего к содержанию: *Девчушка (как же ее звали?) шла по улице; На остальных досках шахматисты одержали восемь (!) побед*.

И вот еще нашел (rusyaz.ru/pr/pvs.html) **Примечание 2**.

В восклицательных предложениях знак восклицательный может ставиться после каждого однородного члена для обозначения эмоциональной прерывистости речи, например: *Пил мёртвую! не спал ночей по девяти! Всё отвергал: законы! совесть! веру!* (Грибоедов).

Comment: Спасибо! Срочно ставь мне пятёрочку - не терплю чётных чисел!